# Sorted Linked List of structs where a struct gets lost

Tags: c++, linked-list

I can't figure out where my logic goes astray in the following lines of code. The linked list is at nodes inside of a Binary Search Tree. Below is my function for sorting the linked list by strings using the compare function

```
void addNewLLObj(TreeNode *tNode, int ranking, string title, int year, float rating){

    LLMovieNode* newNode = new LLMovieNode(ranking, title, year, rating);

    LLMovieNode* crawler = tNode -> head;
    LLMovieNode* prev = NULL;

    while(crawler != NULL){

        if(crawler->title.compare(title) > 0){ // checks if the current nodes title is larger than insert title

            if(crawler == tNode->head){

                newNode->next = crawler;
                tNode->head = newNode;

            }
            else{

                prev->next = newNode;
                newNode->next = crawler;

            }

        }
        else if(crawler->next == NULL){

            crawler->next = newNode;
            newNode->next = NULL;

        }

        prev = crawler;
        crawler = crawler->next;

    }

}
```

If I give title strings "Dccc", "Daaa", "Dfff", "Dzzz", "Deee" in that order

I will lose the "Dfff" string when I print the linked list. I am sure my linked list traversal is correct. I just can't figure out where the logic is wrong. I am not sure if I am overwriting "Dfff" somewhere or If I have a memory leak.

Comment: Why are you using compare instead of the operator < for objects of the type std::string?!

Comment: The function inserts nothing if the list is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop always runs to the end of the list.  Even after it found where to insert the new node.  This can cause you to add the new node multiple times, causing some of your nodes to disappear from the list.

The solution is simple:  Add a `break` in your code to break out of the loop after adding in `newNode`.